# Wait the result of an activity

Tags: java, android

I have a class(A) who need to take a picture, so I create an other class(B) with this responsibility. But the problem is, that A don't wait the result of B. How can I do that?

Here is my code :

**Class which take the picture**

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
Bitmap image = null;

public void takePicture(Context context, Activity activity) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
    try {
        wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        image = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    }
}

public Bitmap getImage(){
    return image;
}
```

**The method which call the the Camera class**

```
 public void openCamera() {

    Bitmap image = null;

    camera.takePicture((Context) _addView, (Activity) _addView);
    image = camera.getImage();

    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
    byte[] picture = outStream.toByteArray();

    _addView.SetCameraPicture(picture);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't a class here be an Activity?! And if Class A needs to take picture, why did you assign this to another class? You can simply do it from inside Class A (which actually should be an Activity!) Also you should not play with the threads ! So the entire approach IMHO is incorrect.

Comment: I assign this to another class because i will need to use this code more than once, so I try to respect DRY principle.

Comment: I don't get it, you have a `getImage()` method, call it wherever you want, do as @Yahya said, _simply do it from inside Class A_ then assign the bitmap to a global variable, create a Model class to hold your bitmap with setters and getters, isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While taking pictures what you are doing is opening another app(startActivityForResult) which is capable of taking pictures. When the app finishes taking the picture you are sent the data through an intent which you listen using onActivityResult. The other class B must be an
Activity(startActivityForResult() can be called only from an Activity).
So with your scenario, you must first open Activity B, then take the picture,
put the result into an intent and start Activity A with that data, which just does not make any sense. If you want to follow DRY principles put your photo taking method into a utility class and dependency inject your class to wherever you need it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank's for your help, your comment really help me so a found a solution

Answer (score -1):

You can always try to make class B async and then let class A await the method of class B

Comment: Can you please show an example of how you make a Java class async?